# Using Google Guice within Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, guice

Is there a comprehensive discussion of the approaches of using Google Guice in the context of Eclipse plugins? There is the Peaberry project that targets OSGi containers in general, but this seems not to be used much in production plugin projects, which makes me a bit skeptic to use it (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) and [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/index.html) wiring is done with Guice. This includes the non-Eclipse relevant parts but also the Eclipse plugins and UI components.